# Print Opposite Triangles function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, c++14

Our assignment is to write a recursion that can print something like this:

```
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

I wrote my code and was hoping to get the right graph. But instead, I got this:

```
* * * *
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

I cannot figure out why. I thought every time my code calls printOppositeTriangles(n-1), it will need to go through everything which include the for loop(the one with j) before the next printOppositeTriangles(n-1) was called. Can someone please tell me why? Thank you!

```
void printOpositeTriangles(int n){
    using namespace std;
    if (n==1){
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
    } else {
        for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        printTriangle(n-1);
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: and forgot to say, I tried my code with n = 4.

Comment: Did you try to run your program in a debugger and step line by line through your code?

Comment: What's `printTriangle`, and how, if at all, is it related to `printOpositeTriangles`? You say "recursion", but `printOpositeTriangles` doesn't in fact call itself recursively.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok so basically in my homework i was supposed to write a recursive function called printTriangles and another one called printOppositeTriangles and I was intended to call PrintOppositeTriangles again but that was just a typo.... so basically I spent half an hour and failed because of this typo lololol. Anyways, thanks a lot. Problem solved now.

Comment: @regulus you need to learn how to use a debugger.  Typos will happen, and without debugger skills you won't be able to work out what went wrong.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am taking a class and it seems like we have not got into that part... also because of the fact there is another printTriangle function I guess it will not really be an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big problem in your code: you need to have a recursive call in printOppositeTriangles. You are calling print triangle which is not the same function name
as printOppositeTriangles. This is the main idea of recursion and it doesn't present in your example.

Try this

```
void printLine(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 1){
        std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            std::cout << "*";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        printLine(n - 1);

        for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            std::cout << "*";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I was intending to call the function itself but somehow it was a typo.

Comment: Is there a way I can mark this problem as no longer needs help?